Using qubit mapping in the Hubbard model to describe Cooper pair entanglement and teleportation
I'm exploring how the Hubbard model might be used to represent superconductivity, particularly regarding the entanglement properties of Cooper pairs. When a Cooper pair forms between two fermions on the same site, they are expected to exhibit some degree of entanglement due to their paired nature. Is there a formal way to describe or quantify this entanglement within the Hubbard model framework?
Additionally, when using a two-qubit mapping per site to represent both spin-up and spin-down states, could this mapping lend itself to describing processes analogous to quantum teleportation? If so, how might one conceptualize or implement teleportation in this framework? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding if the entanglement properties of Cooper pairs on different sites can be harnessed in a way that parallels teleportation protocols.
